# Cannot access state property in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have two arrays in state:

```
const [offers, setOffers] = useState([]);
const [redemptions, setRedemptions] = useState([]);
```

I am updating the properties within this function below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);

const getData = () => {
  Promise.all([getVenue(), getUserData(), getOffers(), getRedemptions()])
    .then(() => {
      console.log("OFFERS", offers); // HERE ARE THE OFFERS: [] ??
      console.log("REDEMPTIONS", redemptions); // HERE ARE THE REDEMPTIONS: [] ??
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
};

const getOffers = async () => {
  const offers = await fetchOffers(id);
  setOffers(offers);
};

const getRedemptions = async () => {
  const redemptions = await fetchRedemptions(user.uid, id);
  setRedemptions(redemptions);
};
```

However, after all the functions have completed I need access to offers and redemptions and my console logs are returning empty arrays, although my UI is updating with the correct values.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Setup a `useEffect` with `offers`, `redemption`s, etc in the dependency array. That's where you correctly get values after react's state update.

Comment: I think this may be the right approach, however, I need to only run this new useEffect once I have ensured the calls for offers and redemptions have completed. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You won't have to worry about calls being completed, just check for the values inside `useEffect`, if they're not `null` and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how `offers` and `redemptions` are `const`. The values of these don't change in the current execution of your component/function when you call the `setXYZ()` functions, so the code within your `.then()` only sees the original unchanged empty arrays. Their values only "change" when your function rerenders/executes again and recreates the variables for that new execution of your component/function. It's the same reason why if you have a function, `foo`, the variables created inside `foo()` are scoped to that execution, and won't change if you happen to call `foo()` again

```js
function foo(call) {
  const bar = Math.random();
  console.log(`bar for fucntion call ${call} is`, bar);
  setTimeout(() => { // "fake" 
    console.log(`After timeout, bar in ${call} is`, bar);
  }, 1000);
}

foo(1);
foo(2); // This doesn't change the value of `bar` in the first function call
```

You can find out more information on this in the question - [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

What you really should do if you want to access `offers` and `redemptions` in your `.then()` callback is have `getOffers()` and `getRedemptions()` return promises which resolve to the `offers` and `redemptions` values respectively. You actually already have functions which do this, `fetchOffers()` and `fetchRedemptions()`. This way, you can remove the `getOffers()` and `getRedemptions()` functions and call your state setter function in your `.then()` callback (note: if you don't want to call them in the `.then()` callback you can keep what you have now, but `return` the `offers` and `redemptions` values from your async functions). This has the added advantage keeping your `.then()` from firing after you've rendered and using values that might no longer be relevant.

```js
Promise.all([getVenue(), getUserData(), fetchOffers(id), fetchRedemptions(user.uid, id)])
    .then(([venue, userData, offers, redemptions]) => { // destructure the resolved values from each promise
      console.log("OFFERS", offers);
      console.log("REDEMPTIONS", redemptions);
      // My suggestion here is to perform the setting in the `.then()` so that your callback logic that uses the offers and redemptions values are the same values which the user sees via the state values:
      setOffers(offers);
      setRedemptions(redemptions);
    })
```

Also, you should consider using a [cleanup function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters) as part of your `useEffect()` that provides the capability to cancel outgoing requests to avoid trying to update the state of a component when it no longer exists.

Comment: Yes, de-structuring the response is the way to to here, now I have access to the arrays within the then block. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Just update the code accordingly!

```
const getOffers = async () => {
  const offers = await fetchOffers(id);
  setOffers([...offers]);
};

const getRedemptions = async () => {
  const redemptions = await fetchRedemptions(user.uid, id);
  setRedemptions([...redemptions]);
};
```

This will create a shallow copy of the response and set the new value to the state.

Comment: This is setting my arrays to [] ??

Comment: Doesn't resolve OP's issue